# WSDL into .NET core project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, soap, .net-core

I had worked before with WCF apps and there was no issue but now with this service I experienced some issues. I am not sure what is the reason behind but I cannot add  https://smp.difi.no/ws/2.0?wsdl in my project.

The error I am also getting is the following:

```
Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://service.elma.difi.no/']/wsdl:binding[@name='ElmaServiceImplServiceSoapBinding']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://service.elma.difi.no/']/wsdl:service[@name='ElmaServiceImplService']/wsdl:port[@name='ElmaServiceImplPort']
Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='no:difi:elma:smp:webservice']/wsdl:portType[@name='difi']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://service.elma.difi.no/']/wsdl:binding[@name='ElmaServiceImplServiceSoapBinding']
Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: These members may not be derived.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='no:difi:elma:smp:webservice']/wsdl:portType[@name='difi']
```

Any idea what is going wrong here? Tried it from SoapUI and works fine but not from VS.

Comment: Google `Error: These members may not be derived.` for some pointers.

Comment: Using the not-core framework you can resolve this with /wrapped on the command line, VS seems to do that automatically.

Comment: There are dotnet core commandline tools, but I have no experience using them.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your web service endpoint's WSDL uses a different way of storing the XML operation data. As Henk points out, using the `wrapped` flag when manually running the **[dotnet-svcutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide)** tool is the solution here.

1. Edit your `.csproj` file and add the following node inside the `<ItemGroup>` node:

`<DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-svcutil" Version="1.0.*" />`

1. Open up a PowerShell terminal from within the folder where the `.csproj` file resides.
2. Run `dotnet restore`.
3. Run `dotnet svcutil https://smp.difi.no/ws/2.0?wsdl -wr`.

The tool should now have generated the necessary artifacts inside `ServiceReference1\Reference.cs`.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, if the underlying service is using SOAP 1.0 then you will still receive theses errors. The two options would be to update the service to be compatible with SOAP 1.1 standards or create a separate .NET Framework app and integrate with it.